# How to move key resources table from word to overleaf

Tags: tables, overleaf, word-to-latex

I have this big table a scientific key resources table as shown in the Journal of Neuroscience, (attached), and it extends further. I have written it in word, but have been struggling to move it to overleaf. I tried the website which converts them for you, but overleaf didn't recognise that format. I have tried taking images (png) from Excel and what not to put in overleaf, but that doesn't work too well either. Any suggestions/is there an already existing template for this sort of table? Help would be hugely appreciated!!!

[image: table to move from word to overleaf]

Comment: You can try using tabular. Welcome to TEXSE. Nevertheless, in this site it's better if you show us what tried so-far. I'm voting to close this as too broad.

Comment: When you write that you want to "move [the table] to overleaf", do you actually mean to say that you want to move it to LaTeX? (Overleaf is an online front-end for LaTeX.) Please clarify.

Comment: Export the table from Word as an comma separated file (CSV) and convert it to a LaTeX table with the help of [csvtools](https://ctan.org/pkg/csvtools).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to copy and past the text from word and then use a couple of minutes to manually add the latex markup. This way the table will be much cleaner than auto-generated tables form websites.

A starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|}
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!50!white!90!yellow}\bfseries Reagent or Resource & \bfseries Source & \bfseries Identifier\\\hline
\rowcolor{blue!50!white!90!yellow}\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\bfseries Experimental models: Organisms/Strains}\\\hline
Mouse: $App^{xxxxxx}$ & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Prof. Takaomi Saido}\\\hline
Mouse: $App^{xxxxxx}$ & The Jackson laborartory & Stock \# : 000664\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT:

Filling the whole text width

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\keepXColumns

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}|X|X|X|@{}}
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!50!white!90!yellow}\bfseries Reagent or Resource & \bfseries Source & \bfseries Identifier\\\hline
\rowcolor{blue!50!white!90!yellow}\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\bfseries Experimental models: Organisms/Strains}\\\hline
Mouse: $App^{xxxxxx}$ & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Prof. Takaomi Saido}\\\hline
Mouse: $App^{xxxxxx}$ & The Jackson laborartory & Stock \# : 000664\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!! That is exactly what I meant, how can I make the table more elongated though, I want it to reach as far as possible horizontally, I tried \textwidth, but its still much shorter than the text?

Comment: @Dimitra See the addendum